# Null record is inserted into MySQL automatically

Tags: php, html, mysql

I am doing a project wherein, I am having to insert, view and delete records. It works perfectly but for some reason adds a null record automatically. The delete works for other entries but not the null entry.

**INSERT DATA HTML FORM**

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
<head>
    <title>Customers Management Page</title>
    <link rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" href="customers.css">
    <link rel="stylesheet" href="https://stackpath.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/4.5.1/css/bootstrap.min.css" integrity="sha384-VCmXjywReHh4PwowAiWNagnWcLhlEJLA5buUprzK8rxFgeH0kww/aWY76TfkUoSX" crossorigin="anonymous">
</head>
<body> 
    <nav class="navbar navbar-expand-lg navbar-light bg-light">
         <span class="navbar-brand mb-0 h1">Invergment</span>
    <div class="collapse navbar-collapse" id="navbarSupportedContent">
    <ul class="navbar-nav mr-auto">
      <li class="nav-item">
        <a class="nav-link" href="#">Products</a>
      </li>
    </ul>
    </div>
    </nav>
    
    <div class="container">
        <form class="add-customer" action="customer_view.php" method="POST"><br>
        <h2>Add Customer</h2><br>
        <input type="text" name="customer_name" placeholder="Full Name" required/><br><br>
        <input type="email" name="customer_email" placeholder="Email" required/><br><br>
        <input type="phone" name="customer_phno" placeholder="Phone No" required/><br><br>
        <input type="radio" name = "customer_gender" value="male" required> Male  <input type = "radio" name="customer_gender" value="female" required> Female <br><br>
        <input class="add-button" type="submit" value="Add"><br>
        <br>
        </form>
    </div>

<script src="https://code.jquery.com/jquery-3.5.1.slim.min.js" integrity="sha384-DfXdz2htPH0lsSSs5nCTpuj/zy4C+OGpamoFVy38MVBnE+IbbVYUew+OrCXaRkfj" crossorigin="anonymous"></script>
<script src="https://cdn.jsdelivr.net/npm/popper.js@1.16.1/dist/umd/popper.min.js" integrity="sha384-9/reFTGAW83EW2RDu2S0VKaIzap3H66lZH81PoYlFhbGU+6BZp6G7niu735Sk7lN" crossorigin="anonymous"></script>
<script src="https://stackpath.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/4.5.1/js/bootstrap.min.js" integrity="sha384-XEerZL0cuoUbHE4nZReLT7nx9gQrQreJekYhJD9WNWhH8nEW+0c5qq7aIo2Wl30J" crossorigin="anonymous"></script>

</body>
</html>
```

**INSERT AND VIEW PHP CODE**

```
<?php

$customer_name = $_POST['customer_name'] ?? 'null';
$customer_email = $_POST['customer_email'] ?? 'null';
$customer_phno = $_POST['customer_phno'] ?? 'null';
$customer_gender = $_POST['customer_gender'] ?? 'null';


if(!empty($customer_name) || !empty($customer_email) || !empty($customer_phno) || !empty($customer_gender)){
    $host = "localhost";
    $dbUsername = "root";
    $dbPassword = "";
    $dbname = "inventory_management";
    $conn = new mysqli($host,$dbUsername,$dbPassword,$dbname);
    if(mysqli_connect_error()){
        die('Connection Error('. mysqli_connect_errno().')'. mysqli_connect_error());
    }else{
        $SELECT = "SELECT customer_email From customer_info Where customer_email = ? Limit 1";
        $INSERT = "INSERT Into customer_info (customer_name,customer_email,customer_phno,customer_gender) values (?,?,?,?)";
        $stmt = $conn->prepare($SELECT);
        $stmt->bind_param("s",$customer_email);
        $stmt->execute();
        $stmt->bind_result($customer_email);
        $stmt->store_result();
        $rnum = $stmt->num_rows;
        if($rnum==0){
            $stmt->close();
            $stmt = $conn->prepare($INSERT);
            $stmt->bind_param("ssis",$customer_name,$customer_email,$customer_phno,$customer_gender);
            $stmt->execute();

            echo "Customer is added";


        }else{

            echo "This email is already registered";
        }
        $stmt->close();
        $conn->close(); 
    }
    }else{
        echo "All fields are to be filled";
        die();
    }

?>



<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
<head>
<meta charset="utf-8">
<title>View Records</title>
<link rel="stylesheet" href="css/style.css" />
</head>
<body>
<div class="form">
<p><a href="#">Home</a> 
| <a href="customer_insert.html">Add new customer</a>
<h2>Customer Details</h2>
<table width="100%" border="1" style="border-collapse:collapse;">
<thead>
<tr>
<th><strong>Sr No</strong></th>
<th><strong>Name</strong></th>
<th><strong>Email</strong></th>
<th><strong>Phone No</strong></th>
<th><strong>Gender</strong></th>
<th><strong>Edit</strong></th>
<th><strong>Delete</strong></th>
</tr>
</thead>
<tbody>
<?php
$host = "localhost";
    $dbUsername = "root";
    $dbPassword = "";
    $dbname = "inventory_management";
    $conn = new mysqli($host,$dbUsername,$dbPassword,$dbname);
    if(mysqli_connect_error()){
        die('Connection Error('. mysqli_connect_errno().')'. mysqli_connect_error());
    }else{
$count=1;
$sel_query="Select * from customer_info";
$result = mysqli_query($conn,$sel_query);
while($row = mysqli_fetch_assoc($result)) { ?>
<tr><td align="center"><?php echo $count; ?></td>
<td align="center"><?php echo $row["customer_name"]; ?></td>
<td align="center"><?php echo $row["customer_email"]; ?></td>
<td align="center"><?php echo $row["customer_phno"]; ?></td>
<td align="center"><?php echo $row["customer_gender"]; ?></td>
<td align="center">
<a href="customer_edit.php?customer_email=<?php echo $row["customer_email"]; ?>">Edit</a>
</td>
<td align="center">
<a href="customer_delete.php?customer_email=<?php echo $row["customer_email"]; ?>">Delete</a>
</td>
</tr>
<?php $count++; } }?>
</tbody>
</table>
</div>
</body>
</html>
```

Comment: when you refresh `INSERT AND VIEW PHP CODE` page it will insert new null records...!!!???

Comment: Besides all, you bind `customer_phno` as an integer. Of course, I don't know your exact requirements, but consider that  `+49(123)345678 #9` can be also valid phone number in some cases.

Comment: @AntonyJack YESSSSSS!!! That is what is happening.

Comment: @biesior I changed it to varchar

Comment: Did you read my answer about `null !== 'null'`? it's real problem, the phone number was just a hint.

Answer (score 0):

You need to check `isset($_POST)` before performing insert operation...

in your `INSERT AND VIEW PHP CODE` page

```
<?php
if(isset($_POST)) { //added to your code
    
        ................
        ................
        //your insert codes here
        ................
        ................

} //added to your code
?>
```

Comment: Why is `'null'` a string?

Comment: `null !== 'null'` !

Answer (score 0):

```
null !== 'null'
```

in your case:

```
$customer_name = $_POST['customer_name'] ?? 'null';
```

`$customer_name` (and others) has a `string` value which is not null and not empty, you need to use valid `null` instead and preferably check it with [`is_null()`](https://www.php.net/manual/en/function.is-null.php) function. Also, use `&&` (AND) operator instead of `||` to make sure that all conditions are checked;

```php
<?php

$customer_name = $_POST['customer_name'] ?? null;
$customer_email = $_POST['customer_email'] ?? null;
$customer_phno = $_POST['customer_phno'] ?? null;
$customer_gender = $_POST['customer_gender'] ?? null;


if (
    !is_null($customer_name)
    && !is_null($customer_email)
    && !is_null($customer_phno)
    && !is_null($customer_gender)
) {
    // INSERT to DB
} else {
    echo "All fields must be filled";
    die();
}
```

can be also convert in other direction

```php
if (
    is_null($customer_name)
    || is_null($customer_email)
    || is_null($customer_phno)
    || is_null($customer_gender)
) {
    echo "All fields must be filled";
    die();
} else {
    // INSERT to DB
}
```

I'd choose the second approach, as it will stop checking if will find first null value;

### Usage of `is_null` is simple

```php
$var = null;

if(is_null($var)){ // litteraly means: if $var is null 
    echo 'Variable $var is null';
}
```

or you can check if something is NOT null;

```php
$foo = 'Some message';

if(!is_null($foo)){ // literally means: if $foo is not null
    echo 'Variable $foo is NOT null and has value' . $foo;
}
```

Comment: How do I use it? The is_null() function

Comment: Did you try to run my code? it's quite simple, check my edit.